# Android Help - Dynamic ImageViews?

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

so I'm looking for a solution where I can add new imageviews, and when I remove one, the rest adjust.
I've included a poorly drawn example of what I mean - when we remove the "man" imageview, everything else shifts to the left. I'm pretty new to Android development so I'm not sure if this is possible/what type of layout I would need/which terms to search. Any help would be appreciated!

before removal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTbrM.png

after removal: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LBJrH.png

Comment: can you share your what you have tried...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply just use the GridView for this. Update the records when you take the action for deleting the item from the GridView, and make it notified your GridView can automatically make it for you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are about just put them and remove one photo by clicking button so its simple .. but I 'm not sure what you want exactly ... any why if this is the case you can but the images pathes in an Array `int[] imagesArray = {R.raw.firs_img, R.raw.second_img .....}` and set the photos `imgView1.setImageresource(imagesArray[varieble])` by clicking a button you can change the variable so you can change the photo
you can give the code to help you better abd give us more infrmation about wha tyou want to do